# Heroku mongodb scheduled query

Tags: mongodb, heroku

I need to run a scheduled task for a mongodb query once a month. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I didn't write the app, but I need to do some improvements. I'm hoping to do this with an add on possibly or something else that doesn't require me to modify the source code of the original application.

I haven't tried too much, because I'm not sure where to start.

This is the command that the web interface would run today if done manually. I need to automate this process. I caputred this using papertrail in Heroku. 
Delete records with query:  { find: { created_at: { '$lte': '2019-06-05' } }, count: 10 }

Expected result is I can schedule a query to run once a month and it succeeds.

Comment: Have you searched for a solution? Maybe something like, say, "heroku scheduler"? What did you find?

Comment: I did. I found 2 add-ons that do scheduling, but I was not able to find any way to get them to connect to a mongodb. Obviously this is beyond my area of expertise. I can try this method if it is still considered a good way to go about this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33354070/how-to-run-a-mongo-script-from-heroku-scheduler

Comment: So it sounds like you've got the answer to your scheduling question. Is your question really how to write a script that deletes objects using the query in your question?

Comment: If that is the recommended approach, then yes, I know where to start with scheduling. My next question would likely be how to script it. I apologize for my ignorance or if this is the wrong place to ask. The Heroku support section pointed me here. If this were a local SQL,Oracle, MySQL, Postgres, etc instance, I could do this stuff very easily. I have many years experience there. I do not have much MongoDB or Heroku experience. I appreciate the assistance.